# Get the Mongo hosts from a client

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a `MongoClient` instance that is connected to a database. I would like to get the connection information (such as the host IP).

How would I do this?

(I cannot for the life of me find it in the docs)

Comment: use `dir(client)` on your client to list available functions / attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.address), you can use `client.address`, if you're using version 3 or above.

Example:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> client.address
('localhost', 27017)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it just returns None.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer (as of 2024) is:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> list(client.topology_description.server_descriptions())
[('localhost', 27017)]
```